# Call PHP function using HTML element

Tags: php

it is possible to call PHP function using HTML element as call to JavaScript function, as

```
<?php

function fname() { code to be excuted }

?>

<input type="button" value="call php function" onclick="fname()" />
```

I tried what is written but it was not successful.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You can't execute a PHP function directly using `onclick` handlers. Either write the function in JavaScript, or use AJAX to handle these.

Comment: PHP is on the server, and Javascript is on your computer. You cannot trigger PHP functions without submitting data to the server. You can do something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this instead:

```
<?php
    function f() {
        echo "method called";
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        f();
    }
?>
```